# C++ CLI error C2228

Tags: c++-cli

I'm working on a C++/Cli project, so I defined my struct like this.

```
  ref   struct  token_t
    {
    public :
        static TokenTypes_t TokenType;      ///enum class

        static String ^      TokenString;   ///enum class

        static Keyword_t  KeywordID; ///enum class

        static  int        IntVal;     
        static  char       CharVal;    

        static  Operator_t OprID;     ///enum class

    };
```

I passed an instance of this struct as a function parameter, but when I tried to do something like : `token.TokenString.pop_back();` it says :

```
Error   11  error C2228: left of '.pop_back' must have class/struct/union
```

Comment: I don't use C++/CLI, but I'm guessing you need to use the arrow with managed pointers.

Comment: Use `->` instead of `.`

Comment: i cant it says that pop_back is not a member of System::TokenString

Comment: @KamalChakib Well it isn't... System::String (which is how you declared TokenString) has no member pop_back.

Comment: i know that , i was trying to answer Alvin wong , i tried to dp something like

token.TokenString = token.TokenString.substr(0, token.TokenString.size()-1);

but still not working (the same problem )

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare the struct statics somewhere? From your code it is not apparent if you did that or not. If you did not, then mere struct instantiation would NOT get you static member instantiation. You need to instantiate the static members *somewhere*. Something like

```
struct  token_t::TokenString = "foo"; (correct the syntax if wrong)
```

Comment: OK but where should i do that ?! in the function ?

Comment: I miss the code that you posted. 

Put the line that I wrote above in a C++ source file, outside of any function. Typically you put that line in the file that defines the class. You cannot put it into header because then you would get multiple copies of the static.

Comment: thank you @Amit Agrawal , and thank you all . actually i converted all my program line by line to CLI and guess what....it took me the hole day byt its working . for that pop_back() problem i just used David Yaw's solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

First, a System::String (the String^ you declared) doesn't have a pop_back method. Look it up on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) for more info.

Second, you declared it static. You are trying to use it with an instance. That doesn't match. Most likely, you don't want any of that static stuff. Remove it.

You also need to access methods of a XXX^ type with the -> operator as if it were a normal pointer.

Comment: **You also need to access methods of a XXX^ type with the -> operator as if it were a normal pointer.**

i didnt get this part , can you explain more please

Comment: If you have a variable "String^ text;", you will need to call "text->Trim();" with the operator for pointers (->) instead of the normal dot for non-pointers. "text.Trim();" will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the arrow access operator. Other then that, you seem to use System.String as if it was std::string from the native C++ standard library...

Comment: any idea how to access the pop_back ?

Comment: You can't access pop_back since there isn't any. Use the System::String API.

Answer (score 0):

OK, several things:

- `String^` is a reference type, you need to use `->` rather than `.` when calling methods on it.
- There is no method `pop_back` on the string class.
- TokenString is declared `static`, therefore the proper way to access it is `token_t::TokenString`. If it's static, it's not associated with a particular instance of the type, only with the type itself.
- You've got the type declared as `ref struct`. This is perfectly valid, but confusing. The `ref` wins out over the `struct`, so what you have is the same as `ref class`. If you want a struct (i.e., a value type, not a reference type), you should say `value struct token_t`. (`value class` will give you the same result as `value struct`, but that's again confusing.)
- The proper members of the [String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) class are SubString, and Length. Therefore, the line to remove the last character from the string would be this:  `token_t::TokenString = token_t::TokenString->SubString(0, token_t::TokenString->Length - 1);`

Comment: Error 9 error C2227: left of '->SubString' must point to class/struct/union/generic type